# Artifacts in Natural Earth Data railroad map

Tags: d3.js

I ran through Mike Bostock's [Let's Make a Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) tutorial and I was so pleased with the results I decided to add some railroad data from the Natural Earth data set.

Most of it renders okay, but there are some crazy artifacts where it seems unrelated meshes are somehow being connected together:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6e2rOpUwmtea3d4enNjY3dSbkk/edit?usp=sharing

I separated the rail data into 3 files to see if that would help fix the problem:

```
for country in CAN MEX USA
do
    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON \
    -where "sov_a3='${country}'" \
    railroads_${country}.json ne_10m_railroads_north_america.shp
done
```

I'm rendering them using topojson.mesh as follows:

```
svg.append("path")
  .datum(topojson.mesh(na, na.objects.railroads_USA))
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("class", "railroad_USA");
svg.append("path")
  .datum(topojson.mesh(na, na.objects.railroads_CAN))
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("class", "railroad");
svg.append("path")
  .datum(topojson.mesh(na, na.objects.railroads_MEX))
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("class", "railroad");
```

[image]

Otherwise my code is virtually identical to that provided in the demo.

How can I get rid of these straight lines?

Comment: Looks like it could be artefacts in the actual data, i.e. you would have to clean that.

Comment: I'm sure it's data-related, but unclear if it's inherent in the dataset or if it's just the way I'm using it. I might need to ensure that unrelated mesh data aren't being connected together. If I dump everything into one file, none of the Canadian railroads show up but there are more straight-line artifacts.

Comment: The entire railroad mesh is a single path. At least some of the artifacts come from the connections between the lower 48 US mesh and the one in Alaska.

Comment: You could check the data in a program such as [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

Comment: QGIS looks wonderful. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a separate path for each railroad. A single file is sufficient:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON \
    -where "sov_a3 in ('CAN', 'MEX', 'USA')" \
    railroads.json ne_10m_railroads_north_america.shp
```

Instead of creating a single mesh, multiple paths can be created as follows:

```
svg.selectAll(".railroad")
  .data(topojson.feature(na, na.objects.railroads).features)
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "railroad " + d.id; })
  .attr("d", path);
```