# D3js SVG open lines display a fill artifact, how to fix it?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, shapefile, topojson

I just added French rivers_lines to my D3js generated SVG. It now display a result like :[image]

I need to keep the river lines without the artifact.

Data : a topojson made of arcs.

**CSS code:**

```
.rivers { 
  fill: none;
  fill-opacity: .1;
  stroke-width:1px;
  stroke: #C6ECFF;
 }
```

same result with some colors and opacity near zero:

```
 fill: #FF0000;
 fill-opacity: .1;
```

**D3 code:**

```
    rivers = topojson.feature(fra, fra.objects.rivers),

    //Append rivers
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(rivers)
        .attr("d", path)

    svg.selectAll(".rivers")
        .data(topojson.feature(fra, fra.objects.rivers).features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "rivers"; })
        .attr("data-name-en", function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
        .attr("d", path);
```

My [full fiddle is temporarily here](https://codio.io/hugolpz/D3-map/Topojson%20v1.html).

**How to fix that ?**

Comment: The problem is that your paths are closed when they shouldn't be. This is most likely cause by an incorrect feature type for the rivers.

Comment: Then related to shp / topojson right ?

Comment: Yes, there's probably something wrong with your data, as the answer suggests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17825112/1974961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a path without any style which seems to be the source of all the black areas. It occurs just between the lakes paths and the rivers paths.

And it looks like this but it's much much bigger:

```
<path d="M254.68465149579959,297.3979576500094L252.63102536206452,297.7622166535384L251.8095749085707,297.7622166535384...
```

If you use Firefox and use its DOM Inspector you can point to a place on the screen and it will highlight the element so you can find the one which is causing an issue.

Comment: Isn't the full solution but point out the trouble. +1 and thanks you !

Comment: Thanks Robert. No one could find a better answer. +1 !