# TopoJSON with strange paths

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I have an ESRI shapefile in WGS84 and convert it to another with a European Albers projection (EPSG:102013) with `ogr2ogr`.

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -t_srs 'EPSG:102013' europe.shp europe_data_wgs84.shp
```

I then convert it to TopoJSON using the following:

```
topojson --id-property iso_a3 -o europe.json -p --simplify-proportion 0.25 --width 900 --height 600 -- countries=europe.shp
```

I then load `europe.json` via D3 and can successfully display it (by setting the projection to `null` as it is already projected).

[image]

Each country of Europe has a class `.country`.

This is what happens when I set `.country { fill: rgb(200,200,200); }`:

[image]

So somehow, the paths are not displayed correctly? I don't understand as the paths seem to render normally without a custom fill. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Symptoms similar to [D3js SVG open lines display a fill artifact, how to fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514039/), but problem seems different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found the problem. I had a `topojson.mesh` layer with class `.country-boundaries` above the country layer, and this mesh had still a fill color defined. So I had to set

```
.country-boundaries { fill: none; }
```