# "stroke-dasharray:x,y;" mess up svg path? (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, svg, d3.js, chromium, topojson

Edit > Fixed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364866

#### Works

I generate svg paths via d3js. Either `data()` + `mesh()` or `datum()` + `mesh()` work.

```
svg.append("g").attr("id","border")
        .attr("style", "fill: none; stroke:#646464;")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data([topojson.mesh(json, L0, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })])
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);
```

or :

```
//inland borders lines
svg.append("g").attr("id","coast")
        .attr("style", "fill: none; stroke:#646464;")
    .append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(json, json.objects.admin_0, function(a,b){return a===b;}))
        .attr("d", path);
```

[image]

#### Breaks

Adding **`stroke-dasharray: 8,4`** result into:

[image]

Changing it to **`stroke-dasharray: 6,3,3,3`** result into:

[image]

Some artifacts appears, and half of the strokes are missing/invisible (borders with Ind/Pakistan, Ind/Nepal, Ind/Myamar, Myamar/Cambodia). If I add a similar stroke-dasharray to the coastline generation, same mess appear with blue lines.

---

**Edit:** Ok. First, i'am squizzed because the topojson.mesh() always return a single MultiLineString which, in turn, generate a single path. But why is it that the "dasharray:none" works fine !??

[image]

**Any idea ?** I think these dasharray makes a portions of the path not closed. (check up ongoing).

Link to live code: https://rugger-demast.codio.io/2_zoom/index.html

Comment: Ok: first, i'am squizzed because the topojson.mesh() return me a single MultiLineString which, in turn, generate a single path. But why is it that the `"dasharray:none"` works fine !??

Comment: It looks like you are using Chrome.  Does the same thing happen on other browsers?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: Works fine on FF. 24h that I battle with this.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, fully-functioning test case that reproduces this problem?

Comment: @Phrogz https://rugger-demast.codio.io/2_zoom/index.html (live coding, will change tomorrow).

Comment: Has been fixed in the meantime: https://crbug.com/438390

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364866

Edit > Fixed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364866

Answer (score 1):

#### Report: (tests ongoing)

- "dasharray:none": works fine, always.
- "dasharray:x,y" : Chrome, unique multilines path `<path d="...."></path>` (open path) = **BUG**
- "dasharray:x,y" : FF, unique multilines path `<path d="...."></path>` (open path) = works
- "dasharray:x,y" : Chrome, path `<path d="....Z"></path>` (closed path) = works
- "dasharray:x,y" : FF, path `<path d="....Z"></path>` (closed path) = works

#### Snapshots

**1) topojson.mesh() => *one* multiline path**

1a) Chrome (fails):

[image]

1b) FF (works!):

[image]

**2) topojson.feature().features => *multiple* polygons (paths)**

**Note:** since polygons received the dasharray styling, borders are dashed twice, generating in cases the illusion of a non-dashed solid line (Ind/Pakistani border).

2a) Chrome (works!):

[image]

2b) FF (works!):

[image]

#### Path svg code

D3 topojson.mesh() generate a **single**, massive multilines path :

[image]

Qualitatively, code is something such this snapshoot and snippet, in much much bigger:

```css
svg { border: 3px solid #6688CC;}
```

```html
<svg width="300px" height="200px" style="fill:#AAEEBB;" >
  <g transform="translate(25,25)" style="fill:none;stroke:#AABBEE;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:4px;stroke-dasharray:8,8,4,4;">
    <path d="M 0,0 L100,0 L100,45
             M0,100 L50,50 L100,125
             "></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

In our dataviz, in `<g id="border" style="...;stroke-dasharray:8,4;"></g>`, this unique `<path d="..."></path>` contains as data all our world's borders arcs at once. As required by svg specs, each arc starts by  `M x,y` and chain a succession of `L x,y`, so we end up with something such :

```
<path d="M 0,0 L100,0 L100,45                  <!-- arc 1-->
         M0,100 L50,50 L100,125                <!-- arc 2-->
         ..."                                  <!-- many more-->
></path>
```

There is no `Z` at these arcs' end, which would wrongly say "connect back to your arc's head". With a general view, all seems good.

I copied-pasted that path to my gedit text editor to use some regex and look for some possible armful `Z` or other. It crashed gedit. No deeper view allowed.

#### Demo

**Minimal demo:** I tried to reproduce the bug with a minimal hand written xml including `stroke-dasharray` but unsuccessfully so far. [Minimal svg demo with basic svg path MLZ explanation](http://jsfiddle.net/jwrmwxzt/6/).

**Huge demo:** On the other end of the scale, my demo implies the generation of a 10MB svg and cannot be ported to jsfiddle easily. For few days, it's available live [there](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/2_zoom/index.html)

#### Mysteries

Why, out of `stroke-dasharray`, the artifacts are **solid stroke** ?

#### Browsers

Chrome: Version 39.0.2171.65 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit);

FF=Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu: 36.0